# Recently started and completed tasks are lost while restart the jbpm-workbench docker

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jbpm, jboss6.x, wildfly-10

I'm working on

> Jbpm-workbench6.5.0Final

Running my docker like with run.sh. File contain

> docker build -t jboss/jbpm-workbench-showcase:test .
>
> docker stop jbpm-workbench
>
> docker rm jbpm-workbench
>
> docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8001:8001 -v /home/msuser1/workspace/wb_git:/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/.niogit:Z -v /home/msuser1/workspace/temp:/jbpm_temp/ -d --name jbpm-workbench jboss/jbpm-workbench-showcase:test
>
> docker start jbpm-workbench

Whenever i restart the container all active tasks are gone. Task id generated form 1, 2 etc. How to get the task what i working before restarting docker container.

Comment: Did you delete the container when restart it? if so, there is some data that you need to save persistently using volume

Comment: Hi @hnandarusdy yes i'm deleting the container. i want to know what data need to save with volume map. Do you have any idea about it?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default H2 database connected. when ever i restart docker its clear the all data. So here i connect with the postgres database. So that works fine without any data lost. I got the concept from the following sources:

> http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-jbpm/jbpm6/configuring-jbpm-6-to-use-a-non-default-database

and

> https://dennis.gesker.com/2016/02/09/adding-postgresql-9-5-datasources-to-wildfly-10/